# java Singleton Infinitely Running Thread : Restart

Tags: java, multithreading

In web server need to continuously poll in order to order to perform some task. Singleton class is implemented so that no developer can accidently create multiple thread. Thread is started on web application startup SingletonThread.getInstance().start(). My problem is health check, In health check I monitor whether the thread is active and if for some reason thread gets inactive, I cannot create new thread since instane is singleton and it throws IllegalThreadStateException when start method is invoked twice on same thread instance. Wanted to know if this can get resolved.

Running thread in singleton class.

Code

```
Class SingletonThread Extends Thread {

      private static SingletonThread objSingletonThread;

      public static SingletonThread getInstance() {

        if (objSingletonThread== null) {
          synchronized(SingletonThread.class) {
            if (objSingletonThread== null) 
              objSingletonThread= new SingletonThread ();
          }
        }
        return objSingletonThread;
      }

    private SingletonThread () {
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      while(true) {
       // some polling code with all exception catch
      }
    }
}
```

Health Check Class method

```
   private boolean isPollingThreadActive() {
       return SingletonThread.getInstance().isAlive();
    }

    public void healthCheck() {
        if(!isPollingThreadActive()) {
           // start thread again
           // cannot use singleton instance because it throws
           // IllegalStateException
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is your class even a singleton?

Comment: `start()` the thread once created, or in the constructor

Comment: I do not understand you problem. Could you be more verbose? Also, you cannot "restart" a thread, it may throw an `IllegalThreadStateException` it you try do do so.

Comment: Does your code work? it is strange :)

Comment: what is resource?

Comment: If you consider thread life cycle, then it should not be singleton. As you cannotfreely restart the thread.

Comment: IllegalThreadStateException will be thrown if you start when you restart thread's start method

Comment: Edited my question based on feedback

Comment: I am not understand why you use Singleton class and Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke single class it is better for you.

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton singleton;

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(){
        if(singleton == null)
            return singleton = new Singleton();

        return singleton;
    }

    public void invoke(){
        //TODO
    }

}


public class MyThread extends  Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Singleton.getInstance().invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: My intent of creating thread class singleton is that no developer should accidentally create another instance of thread class. So that there will be not more than one thread polling the task. So above solution can not be used because we can create multiple insatance of MyThread class [And possibily multiple thread].